# Float and space

Tags: css, css-float

I would like to position 4 blocks : 2 on left and 2 on right.

I can't change the order of the div and d1, d3 must be on right. At the opposite, d2, d4 must be on left. My first thought was to do this :

html :

```
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
<div class="d3"></div>
<div class="d4"></div>
```

CSS :

```
div {
    background-color: red;
    border: solid 1px;
    height: 20px;
}

.d1, .d3 {
    float:left;
    width: 68%;
    height: 50px;
}

.d2, .d4 {
    float: right;
    width: 28%;
}
```

the fact is that d2 and d4 are separated by a space. I was thinking that block will use all the available space.

[image]

How, without changing block order and using only float (no absolute positionning), can I remove this empty space between d2 and d4 ? And additionally, why is there this space ?

here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jjmj2a59/

Comment: Why is there space? Because 68+28=96%

Comment: I talk about vertical space, not the horizontal one ;)

Comment: Thats the way floats work. `d3` starts a new "row" which d4 conforms to

Comment: is the height dynamic or can we rely on you knowing the height of all 4 divs?

Comment: The height is depending on the content. So I can't fix it and I don't know it. For the example I've put a fix height to simulate that.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: damn, that invalidates the answer I just posted. I have a different idea, but I'll have to try that first

Comment: In before someone mentions flexbox...oh wait!

Comment: I edited my answer. And I just had another idea: You said you can't change the order of the `div`s, but is it possible to add another? @Paulie_D what's wrong with flexbox?

Comment: Nothing wrong with flexbox (other than browser support not being super deep)...it would solve your problem I suspect but you insisted on using floats. Is flexbox an option?

Comment: Well Flexbox is not an option because we absolutely need maximum browser compatibility. I think, looking at yours anwsers, that this problem is quite unsolvable...

Comment: I think so too. Last resort: use javascript to reposition your elements and live with the fact that there will be an empty space if javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get it quite right, I have 3 different solutions that almost work but ultimately fail to meet all your constraints:

**First idea: negative `margin-top`**

Drawback: you need to know the height of `.d1` and `.d2`

```css
div {
    background-color: red;
    border: solid 1px;
    height: 20px;
}

.d1, .d3 {
    float:left;
    width: 68%;
    height: 50px;
}

.d2, .d4 {
    float: right;
    width: 28%;
}

.d4 {
    margin-top:-30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
<div class="d3"></div>
<div class="d4"></div>
```

**Second idea: Flexbox in 2 rows**

This is probably the closest to what you want, the only drawback is that `.d2` and `.d4` are vertically centered instead of at the top. Also you need to set some style rules for the parent of your div, but I can't imagine that's a problem.
Also this won't work in IE9 and below and may look a bit different in IE10.

```css
.flex-parent {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.flex-parent div {
    background-color: red;
    border: solid 1px;
}
.d1, .d3 {
    width: 68%;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-align-self:flex-start;
    -ms-flex-item-align:start;
    align-self:flex-start;
}
.d2, .d4 {
    width: 28%;
    height: 20px;
}
.d2 {
    -webkit-align-self:flex-end;
    -ms-flex-item-align:end;
    align-self:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
    <div class="d1">d1</div>
    <div class="d2">d2</div>
    <div class="d3">d3</div>
    <div class="d4">d4</div>
</div>
```

**Third idea: flexbox in 2 columns (incomplete)**

The general idea here is to use flexbox to do this:

1. reorder the elements in the order `.d1` `.d3` `.d2` `.d4`
2. display them in a column
3. align `.d1` and `.d3` to the left and `.d2` and `.d4` to the right edge of the container.
4. force a wrap between `.d3` and `.d2` to push `.d2` and `.d4` into a new column.

I've got 1-3, but I can't get 4 to happen without specifying the height of the container, or a margin that has to be tuned exactly to the height of one of the largest element. Maybe someone else has an idea how to fix that, so here is what I got so far:

```css
.flex-parent {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
}
.flex-parent div {
    background-color: red;
    border: solid 1px;
}
.d1, .d3 {
    width: 68%;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-align-self:flex-start;
    -ms-flex-item-align:start;
    align-self:flex-start;
}
.d2, .d4 {
    width: 28%;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-align-self:flex-end;
    -ms-flex-item-align:end;
    align-self:flex-end;
}
.d1 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group:2;
    -webkit-order:1;
    -ms-flex-order:1;
    order:1;
}
.d2 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group:4;
    -webkit-order:3;
    -ms-flex-order:3;
    order:3;
}
.d3 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group:3;
    -webkit-order:2;
    -ms-flex-order:2;
    order:2;
}
.d4 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group:5;
    -webkit-order:4;
    -ms-flex-order:4;
    order:4;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
    <div class="d1">d1</div>
    <div class="d2">d2</div>
    <div class="d3">d3</div>
    <div class="d4">d4</div>
</div>
```